# Cannot connect to MongoDB Compass using Atlas, even though Compass is installed

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I have installed MongoDB Compass, it is installed in here:

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\MongoDBCompass
```

And I'm trying to connect to Atlas Cluster, using the string which is:

```
mongodb+srv://my_id:<password>@cluster0-8vu0e.mongodb.net/test
```

I typed this in cmd and I get the following error:

```
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I tried to the directory into path but I don't think it worked, I'm still getting an error.
What could be the issue?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me once and it m8ght be because off the whitelist of mongo atlas.

https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/

Comment: I whitelisted my ip but I still get the exact same error. :-(

Comment: Have you tried connecting without the database: mongodb+srv://my_id:<password>@cluster0-8vu0e.mongodb.net without adding test at the end

Comment: I just tired, and still the same error ```'mongodb+srv:' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file```. So I tried to execute in the file where the MongoDB file are, but still doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

**You Can Follow This Code**

```
mongodb+srv://my_id:usingPasswordThisPlaceMongoDBPassword@cluster0-8vu0e.mongodb.net/test
like:
mongodb+srv://my_id:12345@cluster0-8vu0e.mongodb.net/test


**When MongoDB Compass Open...Past Your Url And press Connect Button.**
```

Comment: I get an error of ```'mongodb+srv:' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.``` it seems like my computer doesn't even know it has MongoDB installed.......???

Comment: You need to run mongod first in one cmd window

Comment: When I run mongo first I get error of ```[js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. :``` Do you know why? Previously I didn't get this error but it pops up now..

Comment: This could be because the address was wrong (host or IP) or that it was not running.

Comment: I have whitelist my ip address, but it is still the same..........;-O

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting it with the standard connection string instead of the srv connection string.

You can find the standard connection string in the Atlas UI itself. while selecting for the connection string in the drop down menu of the mongoshell version select 3.4 or earlier then it will give you a connection string which is the standard one like below:

```
mongo "mongodb://cluster2-shard-00-00.dmku2.mongodb.net:27017,cluster2-shard-00-01.dmku2.mongodb.net:27017,cluster2-shard-00-02.dmku2.mongodb.net:27017/test?replicaSet=atlas-1ehx3j-shard-0" --ssl --authenticationDatabase admin  --username <username> --password <password>
```